# How should i check/set the maximum depth level to recursive get directories?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm calling the method like in the given example I set the level to 10.
The BasePath is a directory without any sub directories and only with one file inside.

```
private void  _FileInformationWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            GetFilesAndFolders(BasePath, 10);
        }
```

This is the GetFilesAndFolders method

```
Tuple<List<string>, List<string>> GetFilesAndFolders(string root, int depth)
        {
            List<string> folders = new List<string>();
            List<string> files = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
                {
                    folders.Add(directory);
                    if (depth > 0)
                    {
                        var result = GetFilesAndFolders(directory, depth - 1);
                        folders.AddRange(result.Item1);
                        files.AddRange(result.Item2);
                    }
                }

                files.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(root));
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

            }

            return new Tuple<List<string>, List<string>>(folders, files);
        }
```

In the end i'm getting in this example in folders count 0 and in files count 1.
But I will get the same result also if I set the depth to 1.
And if it was for example the BasePath C:\ I could have more then 10 levels to deep through.

The question is how should I set what is the maximum level the user can set in each case ? In the first example there is only 1 level so it's not logical to that the user will call the method with 10 level. And in the second example C:\ the user can set 10 level and maybe even higher level.

How should I handle it ?

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code, code is already handling maximum depth scenario, what is the exact problem/question?

Comment: If the user has no clue of depth, why even provide a depth argument? The system can figure out the depth, no? I mean it can recursively iterate through all files anyway.